# can't allow relay for privileged IP address centos

Tags: sendmail, centos6, postfix-mta

I want to  allow sending emails through server B using an application hotsted on server A.for that I had to use "allow relay for privileged IP address".
I added "mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8, ip.Of.Server.A/24" to  /etc/postfix/main.cf
but nothing happens after restarting postfix,I'm still getting  550 5.7.1 relaying denied Error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add

```
ipofservera/32
```

By using a /24 it's assuming the network, and you don't want to allow a network to transmit, only a single ip.